# Third Party Companies Providing Mobile App Testing Services

Tags: testing, mobile

We have all of our team run manual tests with release candidates of our app. This is starting to get unwieldy, especially with the varying amount of devices coming out (iPad Mini, are you serious?!).

That being said, we are looking for a third party company that can run a full test suite against our app with all of the supported iOS devices. Can we compile a list of companies offering such services?

*Note: Don't down vote if you think this question isn't appropriate for Stack Overflow. Instead, tell me where on Stack Exchange this post belongs. I think this is a great place for the question.*

Comment: I have two problems with this question: **(1)** it feels like a subtle (or maybe not-so-subtle) advertisement for your app, and **(2)** questions asking for lists of something aren't constructive for this site. However, I'm not sure where it belongs. But I didn't downvote at least.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables edited the question to reflect your first problem. As for your second point, I agree, I'm not sure where else on the Stack Exchange network this belongs. Thanks for not downvoting.

Answer (score 1):

I happen to be recently researching this, here is a short list I have come up with so far:

1. Rainforest - https://www.rainforestqa.com/

   - It uses written plain english tests and Mechanical Turk to let real people run the tests and report issues
   - Mobile web only at this time
2. Applause - http://www.applause.com/

   - Performs real testing in real world scenarios with real people
   - Can do functional, usability, localization, load and security testing
3. TestElf - https://www.testelf.com/

   - Functional testing on real devices, iOS and Android
   - two day test turnaround
   - the will create comprehensive reports with screenshots, test cases, crash logs and repro steps